# Serialising an array of ints within another object

Tags: c#, arrays, json

We're using a custom serializer to serialise c# objects into a json format to intrerface with a REST API. The API expects to recieve data in the following format:

```
    "product": {
        "sku": "211554",
        "extras": [{
                "code": "cost",
                "value": "3.99"
            }, {
                "code": "start_date",
                "value": "2017-01-31T14:27:49.3032432+00:00"
            }, {
                "code": "end_date",
                "value": "2017-02-01T14:27:49.3042537+00:00"
            }, {
                "code": "ids",
                "value": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "19"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

The part of the serialiser just returns the result from

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, _Settings);
```

But results in

```
"product": {
            "sku": "211554",
            "extras": [{
                    "code": "cost",
                    "value": "3.99"
                }, {
                    "code": "start_date",
                    "value": "2017-01-31T14:56:05.4683698+00:00"
                }, {
                    "code": "end_date",
                    "value": "2017-02-01T14:56:05.4693696+00:00"
                }, {
                    "code": "ids",
                    "value": "System.Int32[]"
                }
            ]
        }
```

The serializer seems to work fine on complex nested object types, but not for simple nested types, such as the array of ints in the "ids" section above.

Any idea what needs to be done to get the serializer working recursively on simple nested types?

**UPDATE**

Here's the custom serializer:

```
        public class CustomSerializer : ISerializer, IDeserializer
        {
            private JsonSerializerSettings _Settings;

            public CustomSerializer()
            {
                ContentType = "application/json";

                _Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
                };
            }


            public string Serialize(object obj)
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, _Settings);
                return result;
            }

            public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
            {
                if (response == null) return default(T);
                if (response.Content.StartsWith("{\"messages\":{")) return default(T);

                return response.Content == "[]" ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content, _Settings);
            }

...

    }
```

Comment: Seems like problem goes from *custom serializer* which you are using

Comment: Your example JSON is not valid and you haven't shown what `obj` looks like.

Comment: I reckon the serisalise has a ToString() somewhere that is getting the type rather than the value.

Comment: Show  custom serializer code

Comment: Is it because value changes type form double, datetime to array?

Comment: The issue might be in the definition of your type, specifically the inner type that describes "extras". I am able to generate proper JSON using your custom serializer. How is this type defined (can you please post code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's nothing to do with your custom serializer. I assume the issue is with the class which you're serializing and how you created an instance of it but since you don't show it like I asked I can't tell you for sure.

What I can do is show you how I created the class which serializes correctly.

The class to serialize:

```
    public class Extra
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public object value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public List<Extra> extras { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Product product { get; set; }
    }
```

Create an instance of this class:

```
var root = new RootObject()
{
    product = new Product()
    {
        sku = "211554",
        extras =  new List<Extra>()
        {
            new Extra()
            {
                code = "cost",
                value = "3.99"
            },
            new Extra()
            {
                code = "start_date",
                value = "2017-01-31T14:27:49.3032432+00:00"
            },
            new Extra()
            {
                code = "ids",
                value = new List<int> {1,2,3,19 }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Serialize it as you've already shown:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, _Settings);
```

Output of `json`:

```
{
"product":{
    "sku":"211554",
    "extras":[
    {
        "code":"cost",
        "value":"3.99"
    },
    {
        "code":"start_date",
        "value":"2017-01-31T14:27:49.3032432+00:00"
    },
    {
        "code":"ids",
        "value":[
            1,
            2,
            3,
            19
        ]
    }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer when I posted mine. You're faster, but I think we're on the same page :)

Comment: Turns out the problem was being caused on a deeper layer that handled some data formatting before the above serializer is called. Added an extra case to manage it properly and now it's working as it should. I've marked yours as the answer because it's a solid explanation that might help someone else . Thanks Equalsk

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be in the definition of the type being serialized, specifically in the way "extras" property is defined. Without seeing that type, I tested the following, using the custom serializer you posted, simulating a possible implementation:

```
public class Product
{
    public string SKU { get; set; }

    public ExtraInfo[] Extras { get; set; }

    public class ExtraInfo
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Object to be serialized:

```
var product = new Product()
{
    SKU = "1234",
    Extras = new[]
    {
        new Product.ExtraInfo() { Code = "cost", Value = 3.99 },
        new Product.ExtraInfo() { Code = "ids", Value = new [] { 1, 2, 3 } }
    }
};
```

Serialized using your custom serializer:

```
var result = new CustomSerializer().Serialize(product);
```

Resulting JSON:

```
{  
   "SKU":"1234",
   "Extras":[  
      {  
         "Code":"cost",
         "Value":3.99
      },
      {  
         "Code":"ids",
         "Value":[  
            1,
            2,
            3
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```